# How to inform Picasso that the image in the link changed?

Tags: android, picasso

im using picasso library to load images.
However in my application, users can have profile pictures and the link for the image is constant... Picasso has no clue that the image has changed...

I tried using : `.skipMemoryCache()` but it wasn't an ideal solution...

Is there a way to check if there's a new picture in the same link using picasso? Thanks!

Comment: Please refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/36639357/4749098

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there is no API in the current (2.3.2) version of Picasso to achieve this (but it is a work in progress - see this [bug](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/438)).

That aside, if you have control of the server side, you may want to think about your design decision to provide the changing profile picture at a constant URL.

An alternative would be: Include the current profile picture URL in the profile information you retrieve. This way, your cache can use the cached image - and as soon as the profile information provides a new URL, Picasso will fetch it. In all other cases, Picasso can leverage the cache.

Comment: Loved the alternative solution =)

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer from this [link](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/438)

change your URL as shown below:

```
String imageurl = url + "?time=" + System.currentTimeMillis();

Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageurl).into(imageView);
```

this worked for me. thanks

Comment: Ultimate solution

Comment: It will load the same image every time and consume more mobile data

Comment: This solution only works if you want to reload every time, and if that's the case then the other answers in this question are better practice.

Given that we only want new images when there's a change to the image, this isn't a great solution. :/

Answer (score 3):

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.fit()
.placeholder(YOUR PLACE HOLDER RESOURCE)
.centerCrop()
.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to invalidate the cache like so

```
Picasso.with(context).invalidate(imagePath);
```

The other way to force download the image which then is cached for subsequent use as [mentioned](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/NetworkPolicy.java#L22) in the code.

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(imagePath)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .into(userAvatar);
```