# How do I delete a particular image and clear all images from Glide?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using the Glide library for displaying the images in Recycler View, and when I delete all images, like the below:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
@Override
public void run() { Glide.get(getApplicationContext()).clearDiskCache();}
}).start();
```

It's still reading the images from the cache, and when I go back to the top row in the recycler view, it does not delete all the images from the cache.

Also, can you please help me delete a single image from the cache?

Comment: plz check this ref: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/624 or this so answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443146/remove-image-from-cache-in-glide-library

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, clearMemory worked for me, and i still did not find any way to delete a specific image, Can you please let me know how do i get path where Glide is caching the images? Can i see how many images have been saved to cache at a perticular point of time programmatically?