# Delete cache while using glide

Tags: java, android, caching, android-glide

I know it is a very basic question. I have tried to find the numerous solution but I am not able to understand them.

**What I want**

upload image to the server and in return I am getting URL but the problem is while setting the image using this URL, the old image is set. This is happening because the glide is taking old cache and not updating the cache.

How to solve this.

```
Glide.clear(profilePic);

Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
    .load(url)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .transform(new CircleTransform(MainProfile.this))
    .into(profilePic);
```

currently, the pic is changed but when I click the back button and come back to this activity then it loads an old image. Loading the image from cache like that.

```
//setting up the profile pic
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
.load(userProfilePicUrl)
.asBitmap()
.centerCrop()
.into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(profilePic) {
    @Override
    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
        RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(MainProfile.this.getResources(), resource);
        circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);

        profilePic.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
    }
});
```

The problem is when I come back to this activity it shows old pic instead of new one.

Answer (score 5):

**RequestOptions** provides type independent options to customize loads with Glide in the latest versions of Glide.

Make a **RequestOptions** Object and use it when we are loading the image.

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) // because file name is always same
    .skipMemoryCache(true);

Glide.with(this)
    .load(photoUrl)
    .apply(requestOptions)
    .into(profile_image);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out

```
Glide.with(DemoActivity.this)
.load(Uri.parse("file://" + imagePath))
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.into(mImage);
```

Replacing `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` to `DiskCacheStrategy.NONE`

Comment: no help. when I come back it is showing old image @android_griezmann

Comment: in this case, this will fetch image every time. If internet is not available then image will not display.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal that is correct you can not achieve both at a time as far as I know.

Comment: I think we can achieve that,  most of the app who work offline, they only fetch image if it got changed and show the new one. If internet is not available than it shows new cached image.

Comment: Hey you may be right. It can be done.  I have came across [this link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation) find the `Custom cache invalidation`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this:

```
Glide.get(context).clearDiskCache()
```

[Try reading this link as a ref](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation)

However this solution also seems more provided.

```
Glide.with(Activity.this)
.load(Uri)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.into(Image);
```

Reference to which is similar question asked before, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443146/remove-image-from-cache-in-glide-library).

Hope that helps somewhat.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Glide has inbuilt function  to invalidate cache.By using   [signature()](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#cache-invalidation) function old cache can be invalidated.

```
GlideApp.with(MainProfile.this)
.load(mediaStoreUri)
.signature(new MediaStoreSignature(mimeType, dateModified, orientation))
.into(view);
```