# How to remove glide cache - android?

Tags: android, android-glide

so i use glide everywhere in my app to upload the user's profile image via url. When the user changes their profile picture. I update the backend, so the url is updated. But, glide has cached the old image. How do i overwrite the previous cached image, so that when the user navigates through the app, he/she can see their profile picture change in all activities?

Comment: If the url changes glide downloads the image again

Comment: Please refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443146/remove-image-from-cache-in-glide-library/33451376#33451376. This will help you out for sure.

Answer (score 6):

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) // because file name is always same
                        .skipMemoryCache(true);

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(photoUrl)
                    .apply(requestOptions)
                    .into(profile_image);
```

In the latest versions we should use RequestOptions

RequestOptions Provides type independent options to customize loads with Glide in the latest versions of Glide.

Make a RequestOptions Object and use it when we are loading the image.

Answer (score 1):

Call `Glide.get(context).clearDiskCache()` on outside the UI thread. (also consider `clearMemory()` too to prevent surprises after clearing disk cache)

Read Cache [invalidation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation), because it's not otherwise possible to remove a single file from cache. If you explain your "Clear cache of an URL" use case we may be able to give a better suggestion.

Comment: here he not want to clear cache of gradle but want to remove cache of Glide from imageview to see updated image

Comment: @Jigar Patel, i think you misinterpretted the question. Its when the user is actually using the app

Comment: @TheQ See Updated Answer