# signature() not found in Glide

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I facing issue on Glide, which keeps showing the previous image. I came by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33450182/5156075), which use `signature()` to solve, but `signature()` cannot be solved in my case.

```
Glide.with(activity)
     .load(url)
     .signature(new StringSignature (String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
     .into(imgSignature)
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer.

```
Glide.with(activity)
     .load(obj?.signature_image?.url.toString())
     .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()
     .signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis())))
     .into(imgSignature)
```