# Is there any option for Glide if url is changed then cache will be cleared otherwise load with old image?

Tags: java, android, image, android-glide

i am using glide for showing loading images, and in my app image will be changed frequently, is there any option for clear cache when new image or image will be edited otherwise load old one?

Comment: Is that possible for you share your code / demo ?

Comment: If the url is also getting changed then the cached image wont be loaded as files are cached against url & If it is the image file only that is being changed and not the url, then  what you can do is make two requests, one with caching enabled and one with caching disabled

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 whenever image changes the cache will remove

 Glide.with(YourActivity.this)
.load(Uri.parse(image_url))
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.into(mImage);
```

[refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443146/remove-image-from-cache-in-glide-library) hope it will help you to resolve this issue

Comment: But this disables caching all to gather, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code to achieve the same that you have mentioned in the description above.

```
fun ImageView.loadUrl(url: String) {
    var requestOptions = RequestOptions()
    requestOptions.signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()))
    Glide.with(this).load(url).apply(requestOptions).into(this)
}
```

It's just an extension for the `imageview` and you need to use below way wherever you want this in your app.

```
 imageView.loadUrl(url)
```

Comment: Never use System.currentTimeMillis() as signature. Since this value is always changing, it forces Glide to download again the image every time. It is equivalent to not caching anything.